# In asymptotic notation why we not use all possible function to describe growth rate of our function?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

if f(n) = 3n + 8,
for this we say or prove that f(n) = Ω(n)
Why we not use Ω(1) or Ω(logn) or .... for describing growth rate of our function?

Comment: A higher lower bound is more informative and so more useful. 3n+8 = Omega(1) and 3n+8 = Omega(log n) are both true but say less than 3n+8 = Omega(n).

Comment: If you want to be as specific as possible, you can say f(n) = Theta(n), which means f(n) = O(n) and f(n) = Omega(n)

Comment: Just like most communication, the goal of mathematical statements of complexity is to for them to be useful, not just true.

Comment: For any function you may write f(n)=Ω(1). What use would that be ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust not any function, for example 1/n, but for sure you are right if you limit to any function that describes the space or time of an algorithm.

Comment: @PaulHankin: oops, my bad, you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context of studying the complexity of algorithms, the Ω asymptotic bound can serve at least two purposes:

- check if there is any chance of finding an algorithm with an acceptable complexity;
- check if we have found an *optimal* algorithm, i.e. such that its O bound matches the known Ω bound.

For theses purposes, a *tight* bound is preferable (mandatory).

---

Also note that f(n)=Ω(n) implies f(n)=Ω(log(n)), f(n)=Ω(1) and all lower growth rates, and we needn't repeat that.

Answer (score -1):

You can actually do that. Check the Big Omega notation [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Big_Omega_notation) and let's take `Ω(log n)` as an example. We have:

```
f(n) = 3n + 8 = Ω(log n)
```

because:

[image: f2]

(according to the 1914 Hardy-Littlewood definition)

or:

[image: f2]

(according to the Knuth definition).

For the definition of `liminf` and `limsup` symbols (with pictures) please check [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_inferior_and_limit_superior#Definition_for_sequences).

Perhaps what was really meant is `Θ` (Big Theta), that is, both `O()` and `Ω()` simultaneously.

Comment: Yes we can. But the question is more "why don't we ?"

Comment: @YvesDaoust For the same reason why you normally don't say your `f(n) = 3n + 8 = O(n*n)`, even though it is true. `Ω(n)` carries more information than, say, `Ω(1)`.

Comment: Don't tell me. That is the information missing in your answer.